# Problem: Global variable created from a function won't render in HTML template when using Flask

Tags: python, flask, global-variables, local-variables

I have written a function which when called uses beautiful soup to collect information from a website and save the items in two list variables. I have made these variables global, however I am unable to pass them to flask using render_template().

First I created my function. I have included all of beautiful soup code below, which webscrapes data and puts it into a list, but the important part is the global variable my function creates in the bottom two lines 'global data' and data = list(zipped):

```
def beautiful():

    image=[]
    price=[]

    my_url = str('https://www.websitewithproducts.com/for-sale/')+str(location)
    uClient= uReq(my_url)
    page_html=uClient.read()
    uClient.close()
    
    #parse page
    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
    
    #grabs each product 
    containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class":"results-wrapper"})
    container= containers[0]

    for container in containers:
    #images
        try:
            image_container=container.find("a",{"class":"photo-hover"})
            image_place=image_container.img["data-src"]
            image.append(image_place)
        except TypeError:
            continue
        #prices
        try:
            price_container=container.find("a",{"class":"results-price"})
            price_place=price_container.text.strip()
            price.append(price_place)
        except TypeError:
            continue
        
    
    zipped = zip(image, price)
    global data
    data = list(zipped)
```

Next, I created my Flask app, which calls the function when a post is made to the website by the client:

```
app=Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search_products():

    if request.method == "POST":
        area = request.form['search']
        beautiful()
    return render_template('test.html', data= data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When I run my code and open in browser, it gives me NameError: name 'data' is not defined. My html code is:

```
<body>
    <div class = "form">
        <form method='post'>
            <input type = "text" name = "search" placeholder="Search">
            <input type = "submit">
        </form>
    </div>
    
    <div class="results">
        {% for image in data %}
        <div class = "image">
            <img src = {{image}}>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I think the problem is the data variable I am trying to pass in Flask isn't recognised as the global variable I created in the beautiful() function. However, I can't figure out why. Help would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to assign the result of `beautiful()` to a variable.

Instead of

```
app=Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search_products():

    if request.method == "POST":
        area = request.form['search']
        beautiful()
    return render_template('test.html', data= data)
```

try

```
app=Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search_products():

    if request.method == "POST":
        area = request.form['search']
        data = beautiful()
        return render_template('test.html', data=data, area=area)
    return # whatever you want to show when there is no search, e.g. the search form
```

So, you need to make sure you trigger the search via using post in your search form.

P.S.: no need to use global variables

Comment: I just gave that a go but when I run it in the browser it returns 'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'data' referenced before assignment. Any ideas?

Comment: Ah, right... data is only available within the if-branch - so you did a `get` request and not a `post` request, which will call `beautiful`. I'll update the answer.

Comment: ok. Tried that and for the second render I input render_template('test.html'). This meant I was able to get through to my page with the form. But when I input some text to search in the form, it returned NameError: name 'area' is not defined

Comment: Ok, so you did not show us your `test.html` - looks like you want to use the `area` variable inside. Just like before, you need to pass it into the template. I'll update the answer - once again ;-)

Comment: Ah sorry, it still isn't working. I got "NameError: name 'area' is not defined" again. I've updated my question with the html code if that helps?

Comment: `area` gets defined when you are in the if branch - that means when you send a post request. It does not get defined when you send a get request. Take care which template you return there.